# How do I auto detect a hyperlink while editing?

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, uitextview

Can you auto detect a hyperlink in HTML,JavaScript or Objective C?

Comment: What kind of hyperlink? Are you looking for just a URL or an <a> tag in html, or both?

Comment: Im looking for any URL typed. http://example.com/ www.foo.com. i want it to change into a clickable link while editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hyperlink is part of the html spec.

```
<a href="whoa">blah</a>
```

In any language I'd do an xquery search in the DOM object to find all hyperlinks.

getElementsByTagName('a');